# Solving differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

How can I solve this equation? I have to find `y[x,z];`

```
K + a*Sin[y[x, z]]*Sin[y[x, z]])*D[y[x, z], {z, 2}] - D[y[x, z], x] + 
0.5*a*Sin[2*y[x, z]]*D[y[x, z], z]*D[y[x, z], z] + 
c*P*(2*z - 1)*(b*Sin[y[x, z]]*Sin[y[x, z]] - 1) == 0
```

I need to solve this when the boundary conditions are `y[x,0]=0` and `y[x,1]=0`

I'm a beginner, I don't know *Mathematica* well. I try to solve this with `DSolve`, but it doesn't give me answer.

Comment: Something's wrong with the syntax: after `Sin[y[x, z]]` you have an unmatched right parenthesis. Also, use `k` not `K` (built-in entities begin with upper-case letters; user-defined entities should begin with lower-case letters. And please lose all those totally superfluous `*` signs that just clutter up the expression; spaces between factors in a product suffice.

Comment: No boundary conditions on `x` ?

Comment: `k = 1;
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 1;
P = 1;
eq = (k + a*Sin[y[x, z]]*Sin[y[x, z]])*D[y[x, z], {z, 2}] - 
    D[y[x, z], x] + 0.5*a*Sin[2*y[x, z]]*D[y[x, z], z]*D[y[x, z], z] +
     c*P*(2*z - 1)*(b*Sin[y[x, z]]*Sin[y[x, z]] - 1) == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{eq, y[x, 0] == 0, y[x, 1] == 0, y[0, z] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 20}}];
Plot3D[{y[x, z] /. sol}, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]` Works fine.

Comment: why are you doing `Sin[y[x, z]]*Sin[y[x, z]]` instead of `Sin[y[x, z]]^2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your PDE is highly nonlinear because of the terms `Sin[y[x, z]]`, so I will directly go for a numerical solution utilizing `NDSolve`. But there are quite a few unknowns in your PDE for a numerical solution to be found. So I assigned random values to the different parameters and choose a random boundary condition. Also keeping in mind the suggested correction in the comments.

```
a = 1; K1 = 1; c = 1; b = 1; P = 1;
Eq1 = K1 + a  Sin[y[x, z]] Sin[y[x, z]] D[y[x, z], {z, 2}] - 
    D[y[x, z], x] + 
    0.5  a  Sin[2*y[x, z]]  D[y[x, z], z]  D[y[x, z], z] + 
    c  P  (2  z - 1)  (b  Sin[y[x, z]]  Sin[y[x, z]] - 1) == 0;
ibcs = {y[x, 0] == 0, y[x, 1] == 0, y[0, z] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[Join[{Eq1}, ibcs], y[x, z], {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
    Plot3D[y[x, z] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Edit**
You can download the worksheet from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rw3zt3j8tmd97f1/PDEndsolveAni.nb?dl=0).

Comment: I tried to plot a graph in a mentioned way:  Plot3D[y[x, z] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 10}], but it doesn't plot. Is there another way to plot it?

Comment: @Ani It is generating the plot. I do not know what is going on your end. For your convenience, I have uploaded the MMA worksheet to `Dropbox`. Download it from the link given in the answer.